# Vue js Vuetify custom component not rendered based on the display breakpoint

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a custom component that basically is a v-btn component with specific style. When I'm using it inside v-menu activator with conditional based on display breakpoint, the custom component does not display on the screen. But if I use regular v-btn the button displays properly based on the display breakpoint. What am I doing wrong here?

https://codepen.io/jgunawan-dc/pen/XWzJqRy?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-menu offset-y>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <global-custom-button
            v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown"
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
          >
            Show on medium and lower
          </global-custom-button>
          <v-btn v-else
            color="primary"
            dark
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
          >
            Dropdown
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="index"
          >
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
Vue.component('global-custom-button', {
  template: '<v-btn outlined color="info" @click="$emit(\'click\', $event)"><slot></slot></v-btn>'
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me 2' },
    ],
  }),
})
```

Comment: Could you clarify: do you want to understand **how** this problem can be solved, or understand **why** it happens?

Comment: @dreamwalker both please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are two errors arising from the above scenario:

Error message 1:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node."
```

Error message 2:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
```

This arises when Vue tries to insert an element before another one, but the element no longer exists in the DOM.

In your case, it seams that changing `$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown` from true to false or vice-versa cleans the `global-custom-button` component or the Dropdown `v-btn`.

One possible workaround would be to use `v-show` instead of `v-if`.

A caveat:

> Note that v-show doesn’t support the  element, nor does it work with v-else.

So this suggestion can work (you can change to fit your needs):

```
      <global-custom-button
        v-show="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown"
        v-bind="attrs"
        v-on="on"
      >
        Show on medium and lower
      </global-custom-button>
      <v-btn v-show="!$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown"
        color="primary"
        dark
        v-bind="attrs"
        v-on="on"
      >
        Dropdown
      </v-btn>
```

**EDIT:**

[This works](https://codepen.io/shadrqen/pen/QWOwZao?editors=1010) without `v-if` or `v-show`

Comment: How did you get the 2 error messages? I opened up the Dev Tools when working on Codepen and didn't get those error messages.

Good point on using `v-show`, I actually have tried that but the problem if `v-show` is used is the dropdown menu is not rendered below the button after the button is replaced according to the breakpoint. So let's say you start with `sm` breakpoint, click the button, the menu is rendered properly. Now increase the display size to at least `md`, click the button, now the menu is rendered on the top left of the screen.

Comment: @JohanGunawan I got the 2 errors just by opening the Dev Tools. Sorry you can't see the same? Secondly, `v-show` seems to bring yet another issue bug, possibly related to [this](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2480). However, another alternative in addition to @dreamwalker's answer is [here](https://codepen.io/shadrqen/pen/QWOwZao?editors=1010). Hope this helps

Comment: It baffles me that I am unable to see the 2 errors you are seeing. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you change your Codepen? I looked at your Codepen again today and that gives me the idea to have both buttons in a new component and use the new component as the menu activator. The behavior is now what I want it. Thank you!

Comment: Having the buttons in a different component removes the need to use both `v-if`and `v-show`, solving both of our previous problems. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, use `v-show` as @Rotiken said.

As another solution you could also register two global components and show/hide it using extra `condition` prop:

```js
<v-menu offset-y>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <global-custom-button
      :condition="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown"
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"      
    >
      Show on medium and lower
    </global-custom-button>
          
    <global-custom-button-2
      :condition="!$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown"
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"
    >
      Dropdown
    </global-custom-button-2>
  </template>
  ...
</v-menu>

...

Vue.component('global-custom-button', {
  template: '<v-btn v-if="condition" outlined color="info" @click="$emit(\'click\', $event)"><slot></slot></v-btn>',
  props: ['condition']
});

Vue.component('global-custom-button-2', {
  template: '<v-btn v-if="condition" color="primary" dark @click="$emit(\'click\', $event)"><slot></slot></v-btn>',
  props: ['condition']
});
...
```

According to [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/JjOoeOL), this also works.

---

**Why** this happens and why `v-show` works fine with same template: I can't give an exact answer, but there are some assumptions.

[Vue.js docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show) says that `v-if` removes objects from DOM, whereas `v-show` changes its display state in CSS, but keep it in DOM.

Since you are using `v-if` in a vuetify `v-menu` component, perhaps the component has some methods for updating the `v-slot:activator` content that can conflict (and not performed at the same time) with conditional rendering using `v-if` and vuetify display breakpoints.

If you are familiar with TypeScript, you can look into [v-menu sources](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VMenu/VMenu.ts) or into [activatable mixin sources](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/activatable/index.ts). Maybe here you will find the true reason for this behavior.

If you just want **to avoid** such problems, use `v-show` in such cases.

Comment: Thanks for the CodePen. The solution you propose unfortunately runs into the same issue if I use `v-show`. That is after the breakpoint change, the menu is rendered at the top left of the screen instead at the bottom of the button/activator. This could be a bug in Vuetify.

Comment: @Johan you can add **absolute** prop to `v-menu` to smooth this effect